# FTP download file from server directly into client

Tags: php, ftp, download

I try to download a file from FTP server into client. If I use `ftp_get`, the file is downloaded into PHP server, which can write the output into browser. So the download process is

```
FTP server -> PHP server -> client
```

This doubles traffic - this is bad in downloading big files. There is a way how to write the file directly into the browser described here: [Stream FTP download to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397182/stream-ftp-download-to-output) - but the data flows through PHP server anyway, am I right?

Is there any way how to establish this download (if yes, how?), or is it principially impossible?

```
FTP server -> client
```

**Edit:** it should work also with non-anonymous FTP servers in secure way.

Comment: No, this won't work with password protected servers. The user will have to directly connect to the FTP server, for which he'll need to know the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code for that.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("ls-lR.gz", 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp.sunet.se/ls-lR.gz"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$_FTP[username]:$_FTP[password]");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($curl);
```

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to me to be the best solution, I will make some tests. You could point the original source I have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178425/download-a-file-from-ftp-using-curl-and-php

Answer (score 3):

`<a href="ftp://server/file.ext">Download the file</a>` ;-)

Comment: Pretty simple indeed, but it does not work if FTP login/password is required.

Comment: You could use the `ftp://login:password@server/file.ext` syntax if the login/password is public

Comment: But the login/password would be fairly useless if disclosed in HTML this way

Answer (score 2):

If the client can directly access the file in question (i.e. no secret usernames or passwords necessary), just redirect him to it:

```
header('Location: ftp://example.com/foobar');
```

This will cause the client to access the URL directly. You can't control what the client will do though. The browser *may* simply start to download the file, but it may also launch an FTP client or do other things which you may or may not care about.